# Vue.js - Methods vs Computed. What is wrong here

Tags: vue.js

I've created a Codepen of  very simplified version of an app that I'm trying to build (im new to Vue):

https://codepen.io/dagford/project/editor/XVaaBo

**Problem 1** - I'd like to use `methods` rather than `computed`, however, as you can see what is happening if I use `methods`.

**Problem 2** - the displayTotal function is not working at all (whether I use methods OR computed.

Comment: `I'd like to use methods rather than computed` Why?

Comment: You will want to use computed rather than methods if possible. This is because the computed properties are efficiently cached and only recomputed when property dependencies are updated. It allows you to avoid programming extra logic to check for or trigger updates, and integrates nicely into vue's data binding system. Preferring methods over computed properties will bloat your code, and reduce your opportunities to fully leverage vue's data binding system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

displayNum1 and displayNum2 are methods, but you address them as vars. Try placing () in your html

```
<p>Display number one: {{ displayNum1() }}</p>
<p>Display number two: {{ displayNum2() }}</p>
```

That also applies to your displayTotal();

Comment: I think both works in a same manner until we provide any param for method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use computed for only `total`. [From vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

means if any of its `dependencies` changes it will recalculate

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies.

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    num1: 1,
    num2: 2  
  },
  computed: {
       displayTotal: function() {
             return parseFloat(this.num1) + parseFloat(this.num2);
       }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="app1">
          <p>{{ message }}</p>
          <p>Display number one: {{ num1 }} : <input type="number" v-model="num1"></p>
          <p>Display number two: {{ num2 }} : <input type="number" v-model="num2"></p>
           <p>Display total:  {{ displayTotal }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```